# Let $h(\xi)=x\xi-t(1+|\xi|^\beta)$ for all $\xi\in\mathbb{R}$. Is $h\in \mathcal{C}^\infty(\mathbb{R})$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, continuity

Recall that $h\in \mathcal{C}^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ if and only if $h: \mathbb{R}\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is of class $\mathcal{C}^r$ for all $ r\in \mathbb{N}$, that is, $h$ and its derivatives up to order $r$ are continuous, for all $ r\in\mathbb{N}$.

***I wonder if there exists $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ such that if $\beta\geq\alpha$, then $h\in\mathcal{C}^\infty(\mathbb{R})\quad \left(\mbox{for}\hspace{.1cm} \beta\in(1,\infty)\right)$.***

Note that $h$ is continuous for $\beta\in(1,\infty)$, moreover, this is differentiable and its derivative is $h'(\xi)=x-t\beta |\xi|^{\beta -2}\xi$. It is easy to see that this function is continuous, but it is not differentiable for all $\beta\in(1,\infty).$

As I am interested in knowing from what number $\beta$ the function $h$ is $C^\infty$, for which I need $h'$ to be differentiable, let's note at least we must have $\beta-2>1$, because if $\beta-2=1$ we know that $|\xi|^{\beta-2}=|\xi|$, which is not differentiable at $\xi=0$ (this just to give an example). Now, if we assume $\beta$ such that the following derivatives exist for all $\xi\in\mathbb{R}$, we have:

1. $h^{''}(\xi)=(-t\beta)\left[(\beta-2)|\xi|^{\beta-4}\xi^2+|\xi|^{\beta-2}\right]=(-t\beta)|\xi|^{\beta-2}\left[(\beta-2)|\xi|^{-2}+1\right]$.
2. $h^{'''}(\xi)= (-t\beta)(\beta-2)|\xi|^{\beta-4}\xi\left[(\beta-4)|\xi|^{-2}\xi^2+3\right]$.
3. $h^{(4)}(\xi)=(-t\beta)(\beta-2)(\beta-4)|\xi|^{\beta-4}\left[(\beta-6)|\xi|^{-4}\xi^4+3|\xi|^{-2}\xi^2+2|\xi|^{-2}\xi+|\xi|^{-2}+3\right]$.

After doing the above calculations, I can't see from what possible value $h\in\mathcal{C}^\infty(\mathbb{R})$. Moreover, I do not know if there is such a value, (this is precisely my question). To answer such question, at some point I tried to find a recursive formula for the $r$-th derivative of $h$, but failed to do so.

Comment: You can simplify the initial problem some by simply considering only $g(\xi) = |\xi|^{\beta}$.

Comment: It might also help to consider the piecewise nature explicitly: $$g(\xi) = \begin{cases} \xi^{\beta} & \xi > 0 \\ 0 & \xi = 0 \\ (-\xi)^{\beta} & \xi < 0\end{cases}$$ What value of $\xi$ do you think is the problem child here? Can you see how the piecewise nature helps you with identifying which $\beta$ work?